# How to post object using fetch with form-data in React?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, express

I want to send a file to my express app as backend. My problem is that my body is send as type `application/json` and I want to send this as a `form-data` and later upload this file using `multer` -> https://github.com/expressjs/multer

I don't know how to prepare fetch call to get it later in express.

```
    fetch('/api/data', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/form-data',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
})
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data));
```

When I want to log `req.file` in api breakpoint I'm getting `undefined`.

```
app.post('/api/data', upload.single('cv'), (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.file);
  res.send({ name: 'Hello world!' });
});
```

I store react data from form using hooks and this object looks like this:

```
{
   name: 'test',
   surname: 'test2',
   cv: 'C:\\fakepath\\Babel error.png'
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to build your request body using the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

> The FormData interface provides a way to easily construct a set of key/value pairs representing form fields and their values, which can then be easily sent using the XMLHttpRequest.send() method. It uses the same format a form would use if the encoding type were set to "multipart/form-data".

```
const myFile = document.querySelector("input[type=file]").files[0];
const data = new FormData();
data.append("myFile", myFile);
data.append("otherStuff", "stuff from a text input");
fetch(target, {
    method: "POST",
    body: data
});
```

Comment: req.file still send undefined

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot the file input type acts a little differently. You must refer to Element.files[0]. I corrected my example so it works.

Comment: My pleasure :o)